# Why does my wifi not work?

Tags: networking

Yesterday evening, my connection was working perfectly well. Then I connected to my school's wifi this morning, fine. As I was switching it on, my friend pressed my wifi button. I shut down my computer, 3 minutes later, I switched my laptop on again, it showed 'wireless disabled by hardware switch'.

I tried to press it in different ways, like 5 seconds or double. All I could do is switch the bluetooth on and off. Some times the 'by hardware switch' disappears leaving the disabled behind. I'm using ubuntu 11.04, a single OS in Compaq Presario CQ60 104TU. Please help me with this, I have no idea what it is. I searched all over the cyber world but I didn't find anything that helped me.I only had it working fine for a night Please reply.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information?

Comment: try switching it on or before booting...It might help...

Answer (score 3):

I used to have such problems with 11.04. When I have such problems, I make sure that the hardware switch for the WiFi is not off and then I suspend and resume. Every time, it always work. I guess the problem is with the WiFi drivers in the kernels that work out of the box.